# Using .remove() on select options (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript

By mistake I used `.remove()` on a `option` element and the `option` was removed. That is, the `option` I called `remove()` on was removed from the `select` element. I can't find any documentation on this method of an `option` element.

Is this an undocumented method? If not, why does `remove()` work on the `option` element?

Here's a quick example. We'll create a `select` with 5 `option`s, then remove specific options by calling `options[N].remove()` where `options` is an array containing the 5 options.

```js
const selectEl = document.querySelector('select')

const optionEls = Array.from(selectEl.querySelectorAll('option'))

optionEls[1].remove()
optionEls[2].remove()
optionEls[3].remove()
```

```html
<select>
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
  <option>Option 4</option>
  <option>Option 5</option>
<select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

> The ChildNode.remove() method removes the object from the tree it belongs to.

Please note, however, there is currently no Internet Explorer support for this method.

Answer (score 0):

`.remove()` is also a `DOM` method.

Comment: As in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove?

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Yes. Another way to convey is that jQuery also has a `.remove()` method.

Answer (score 0):

When there are no arguments passed to the remove function, Child node's remove function gets called and thus the node gets removed from DOM.

It is clearly documented

> The HTMLSelectElement.remove() method removes the element at the specified index from the options collection for this select element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/remove

**[ChildNode.remove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove), the method that gets called when remove is called without arguments on a HTMLSelectElement.**

If you look close at the image, you can find the Option's Child node is a Text node and that gets removed.

[image]

Comment: That's a method for `select` elements, as in `SelectEl.remove(0)` to remove the first `option`. I'm calling `remove()` directly on an `option`.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody Options have child nodes too.